# VM Workstation in azure Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, virtual-machines, azure

I have a Virtual Machine windows server 2008r in Azure, wich I connect with remote desktop.

When I'm in the Virtual Machine of Azure, I have a Phisical Virtual Machine of linux, with VM Workstation.

When I try to star The Virtual Machine of VM Workstation, an error ocours:

VMware Workstation and Hyper-V are not compatible. Remove the Hyper-V role from the system before running VMware Workstation.

Can I execute this Virtual Machine? Can I disable Hyper-V?

I have read that I can make a transformation from vmWare to Azure, but I think it's only for not Phisical virtual machines, I don't know if i'm wrong or the documentation is too hard for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not. What you try to do is not supported - nesting VM's. Get multiple azure VM's (of smaller size).

Next generation Hyper-V will support it for Hyper-V. Mostly because cross development in visual studio relies on Hyper-V to start the images you develop in (android phone, windows phone) for debugging.

But this is not really that likely to work across technologies (different hypervisors) and it is not even now.

It generally is not a good idea to do what you do - run up VM's for your VM's.

And no. How do you think you can disable Hyper-V? Hyper-V is what your VM is running- Disabling it would kill your VM and all other VM's running on the same physical host as your virtual machine. It also would be a terrific security issue if a VM could just remove the core component on the host operating system without permission.